# string-append inside recursive function

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Given a structure `layer` defined:

```
(define-struct layer [color doll])
```

I am trying to write a function that will produce a string of colors of all the dolls.

```
; colors: Russian doll (RD) -> String
; consumes an RD and produces a string of all colors
(define (colors an-rd)
   (cond
       [(string? an-rd) (string-append an-rd ",")]
       [else
          (colors (layer-doll an-rd))]))

(colors
  (make-layer
   "yellow"
    (make-layer
      "green" "red")))
```

I would like for `colors` function, given the above input, to produce `yellow, green, red`; however, it only returns `red`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case is in correct (it should simply return a string), and consequently the call to `string-append` is in the wrong place; the idea is to append a piece of the string at each recursive call until there are no more pieces. Try this instead:

```
(define (colors an-rd)
  (cond
    [(string? an-rd) an-rd]
    [else
     (string-append (layer-color an-rd)
                    ", "
                    (colors (layer-doll an-rd)))]))
```

For example:

```
(colors
 (make-layer
  "yellow"
  (make-layer
   "green" "red")))

=> "yellow, green, red"
```